# Passing arguments within --from command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is as shown below which uses alpine envoy image as base image.

```
ARG envoy_image=envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.14.1

FROM ${envoy_image}
COPY --from=myimage:1.1 /usr/local/myproject/myservice /usr/local/myproject/myservice

WORKDIR /usr/local/myproject/myservice
COPY abc.sh /usr/local/bin
```

I'm copying my own service binary file called "myservice" to this base image which works fine. But I want to pass my own image version as an argument and if I use --from tag parameterized, 
the docker compose throws error with invalid reference error. I tried below approaches but none of them worked.

Approach 1:

```
ARG envoy_image=envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.14.1
ARG my_image=myimage:1.1

FROM ${envoy_image}
COPY --from=${my_image} /usr/local/myproject/myservice /usr/local/myproject/myservice

WORKDIR /usr/local/myproject/myservice
COPY abc.sh /usr/local/bin
```

This gives error with invalid reference.

Approach 2:

```
ARG envoy_image=envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.14.1
ARG my_image=myimage:1.1

FROM ${envoy_image} AS release_image

FROM ${my_image} AS my_image
WORKDIR /build
COPY /usr/local/myproject/myservice .

FROM release_image
WORKDIR /usr/local/myproject/myservice

COPY --from=my_image /build/myservice /usr/local/myproject/myservice
COPY abc.sh /usr/local/bin
```

However, above Dockerfile also gives error that its not able to copy /usr/local/myproject/myservice as no such file exists but my image has the file called "myservice" in /usr/local/myproject directory.

Any clue on how to get my image parameterized?

Note: I need to pass my image version only at build time and not when running container.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482

Comment: I already tried that in Approach 2 mentioned above but it just can't find myservice file in my_image at all.